# `purrr:map()` to print items in a list and also their names

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I've got a simple problem that I'd like to be able to use `purrr::map()` on.

I've got a list of named items (this example using the `mtcars` dataset):

```
var_labels <- list(cyl =  "Number of Cylinders",
                  disp = "Displacement")
```

I'm able to print all of the `chr` list items
(printing is a simplification of my real problem):

```
print_label <- function(x){
  print(x)
}

map(var_labels, print_label)
```

Which gives:

```
>[1] "Number of Cylinders"
>[1] "Displacement"
>$cyl
>[1] "Number of Cylinders"
>
>$disp
>[1] "Displacement"
```

But I don't seem to be able to print the list items and their names:

```
print_item_and_name <- function(x){
  print(x)
  print(names(x))
}

map(var_labels, print_item_and_name)
```

which gives me NULLs:

```
>[1] "Number of Cylinders"
>NULL
>[1] "Displacement"
>NULL
>$cyl
>NULL

>$disp
>NULL
```

My real problem is not just printing the items and their names, but I suspect that if I can get a solution to this simplified step, I should be able to solve my real problem.

Desired output would be:

```
>[1] "Number of Cylinders"
>    "cyl"
>[1] "Displacement"
     "disp"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` does not have access to names of the list. For that `imap` is used :

```
print_item_and_name <- function(x, y){
   print(x)
   print(y)
}

purrr::imap(var_labels, print_item_and_name)
```

---

You can also pass `names` separately and use `map2` :

```
purrr::map2(var_labels, names(var_labels), print_item_and_name)
```

which is same as using `mapply`/`Map` in base.

```
Map(print_item_and_name, var_labels, names(var_labels))
```